# Ошибка в функции на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, прогрессия

Программа определяет, является ли последовательность геометрической или алгебраической. Всё работает, но лишь до того момента, пока все элементы в списке не станут типа *float*, в таком случае проверка на *алгебраическую* начинает работать неверно. Пример: 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 – алгебраическая прогрессия с отношением **1.1**, но ф-я возвращает False.

```
sequence = str(input('Введите последовательность чисел: '))
lst = [float(i) for i in sequence.split()]


def is_geometric(lt):
    ratio = lt[1] / lt[0]

    for i in range(1, len(lt)):

        if lt[i] / lt[i-1] != ratio:
            return is_algeb(lt)

    return f'Данная последовательность является геометрической. Её отношение равно {ratio}'


def is_algeb(lt):
    ratio = lt[1] - lt[0]

    for i in range(1, len(lt)):

        if lt[i] - lt[i-1] != ratio:
            return 'Данный набор чисел не является последовательностью'

    return f'Данная последовательность является алгебраической. Её отношение равно {ratio}'


print(is_geometric(lst))
```

[image: работа программы]

Comment: 4.4 - 3.3 = 1.1000000000000005, а 3.3-2.2 =1.0999999999999996

Comment: ну и хороший способ находить ошибки - выводить на печать промежуточные значения. Добавив (например) ``print(lt[i] - lt[i-1])`` в цикл, вы бы уже поняли причину неверного результата.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сравнение чисел с плавающей запятой "в лоб" не работают из-за машинного представления числа. Используйте соответствующую функцию для этого.

```
        if not math.isclose(lt[i] - lt[i-1], ratio):
```

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужно либо сравнивать числа учитывая погрешность, либо использовать тип данных [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), хранящий числа с абсолютной точностью.

Comment: Decimal - хороший совет, если у автора вопроса входные данные всегда будут точно представимы через десятичные дроби. Иначе можно посмотреть в сторону Fraction, который позволяет работать с любыми дробями вообще.